# How to identify the origin of unverified App Check requests

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

I have been using Firebase's App Check for my application's security and I'm facing difficulties in determining the source of unverified requests.

I have already implemented App Check in my application, and verified requests seem to be functioning correctly. The issue arises when it comes to handling unverified requests and gaining insights into their origin.

Is there a way to retrieve additional information or debug unverified requests using Firebase's App Check? I would like to understand where these unverified requests are coming from for further analysis and troubleshooting.